# How to Set Wrap Text To TextBlock in WPF vb.net application

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, textblock

I have an application in which I have to show multi-line text in TextBlock. But the work I have done is not fitting-In . my filed goes under to next field and also No wrapping  or Ellipses showing. Below I am attaching the screen shot of the work and also the XAML of that control's declaration.

[image]

```
        <TextBlock Name="txtblock" Padding="10,0,0,0" Text="" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Calibri" Grid.Column="2" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Width="228" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,0,0,5" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the width property from your TextBlock, this will ensure that your textbox's size is relative to it's parent.

```
Width="228"
```